# Morris chart does not show bars

Tags: angularjs, morris.js

I am using Morris bar chart. I am getting everything good but the bars. The `labels`, data (JSON from server) are showing but bars are not showing. Below is `Bar()` function. I am using `angularJS`.

```
            $scope.xkey = 'a';
            $scope.ykeys = ['b'];
            $scope.labels = ['b'];
            $scope.myModel = JsonData;
            Morris.Bar({
                element: 'Report',
                data: $scope.myModel,
                xkey: $scope.xkey,
                ykeys: $scope.ykeys,
                labels: $scope.labels,
                barColors: ['#51445f']
            });
```

Comment: can you make sure that your data from the server respect the format ?

Comment: Post a plunker of your problem. I suspect value of JsonData

Comment: data from server comes in perfect format.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set height of `<div>` that contains `chart`.

```
<div id="Report" style="height:300px;"></div>
```